# Could antimatter have disapeared from the universe simmilarly as observed matter from collisions of black holes?

Tags: gravitational-waves, antimatter, matter

As matter inside a neutron star or black hole can vanish through collisions could be possible that antimatter did so more than matter in the very beginning of the universe through a high energetic process so a less quantity of antimetter remained and the result of getting anihilated with matter had as consequence predominately matter universe?

Comment: At the beginning there weren't neutron stars and black, the matter antimatter annihilation happened in the very first moments of the universe.

Comment: @AnOrAn I didn't mention  black holes collisions as the cause of  antimatter disappear but asking here about a process that could have provoked same consequences...

Comment: There surely has been a process that caused an imbalance between matter and antimatter in the early Universe, is this the confirmation you wanted? What was the process is unclear today and a topic of research